# Each Android thread is associated with Looper(Message Queue)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to understand threads,handlers,loopers. I have watched the video where guy said following Each Android thread is associated with Looper(Message Queue). So that means that when I am creating Thread class instance it is implictly creates it own looper which is connected to this thread ? Or this is wrong ? Handler is connected to the thread where it was created, if there is no looper in each thread where handler will post messages ?
And another question is about HandlerThread . What is the purpose and what are pros and cons of using this class. 
I hope for your help.Thanks everyone in advance.

**EDIT**
I wonder if Looper is associated with thread after just calling for example 
 `Thread myThread = new Thread();`
Or you should specify explictly lopper for thread calling Looper.prepare(); in your thread in turn implictly creating new instance of looper associated with the thread where method has been called. As I can see in sources of Looper class it calls ThreadLocal.get in prepare where is it gets current thread. So conclusion is that there is no looper associated with simple thread by default ? Am I right ? 
And I have also noticed that all constructors of the Handler call Handler(Callback callback, boolean async).  Looper.myLooper(); method is called.
So as I have understood it means following.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//some stuff here 
}
});
myThread.start();
```

No Looper here is associated with thread.
Next example.

```
  Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    }
    });
    myThread.start();
```

Here Handler will be associated with looper implictly while creating new instance of Handler.
Next example.

```
 Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         Looper.prepare();
        }
        });
        myThread.start();
```

In this example loooper will be created to explictly by calling prepare method.
I am right ? Please comment.

**EDIT 2**

The second example will cause

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare() such exception so conclusion is that
>   only thread that has called Looper.prepare()

; will have it's own Looper otherwise it will cause exception while creating handler inside such thread.

Comment: Mostly right, but your final example is useless.  After calling `Looper.prepare()`, it needs to create a `Handler` and expose it somewhere so that other threads can post to the queue, then call `Looper.loop()` to begin processing the queue.  As you've written it, it will create the message queue, then do nothing and exit.  And BTW, while it's good to know how it works, there are few good reasons to create your own loopers.

Answer (score 2):

A thread becomes associated with a message queue by calling `Looper.prepare()`.  Any `Handler` subsequently created in that thread will be associated with the same message queue.  The thread begins processing its message queue by calling `Looper.loop()`.  A looper thread typically won't do anything except process its own message queue.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup Only if it calls `Looper.prepare()`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Looper and Handler are just helper classes for easily handle generate and handle message in threads. But thread can do anything besides handling message.